# Django Queryset: Filter queryset based on certain column(foreignkey) and filter by year

Tags: python-3.6, django-3.0

If you don't mind am a newbie in django, but passionate about the framework and Python as well. I have a model which I want to make queryset and perfom an operation based on an attribute that is a foreignkey and of current year.

```
class Feepay(models.Model):
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   term = models.ForeignKey(Quarter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   level = models.ForeignKey(Darasa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   paydate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
   receipt_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
   amount = models.IntegerField()
   remarks = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, default = 'received')
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

my problem is I wanted in to add amount to an existing record of a student which has the same term name as the one in the db records of the same created_at year. for eg: if a student made a payment for first term in this year, then I want the next payment installment for first term in the same year should add up to the existing record of the same term. I tried different ways but due to lil ongoing knowledge got stuck up. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Django we have reverse relationship, in which you can query on student model via passing the filter on reverse referenced object Feepay. In reverse relationship pass the lowercase name object.

Refer this [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
Student.objects.filter(feepay__term__name__exact="Your_Term_Name")
```

Comment: Thanks comrade, let me give a try on this and get back to you